# Animation not rendering well in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

I'm using a card for news block.

On hovering the card an overlay will appear from the bottom to top (sliding)

Everything goes well on Firefox and Chrome browser when viewing in IE the animation is rendering very bad also it didn't slide the animation

Can anyone guide me I'll attach my code here.

Any improvements, suggestions or alternate solutions were welcomed .

ps: I'm currently using **Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0**

```css
.card_container{ 
        position:relative; 
        width:280px; 
        margin:auto; 
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
        height:450px; overflow:hidden;
      }
.card_text{
       position:absolute; 
       color:#fff; 
       height:100%; 
       width:100%; 
       top:0; 
       left:0;
     }
.card_text .pre_state {
       position:absolute; 
       top:calc(100% - 30%); 
       width:100%; 
       padding:30px 15px 25px; 
       height:100%; 
       transform:translate(0%, -30px);
}
.card_text h5{
       font:14px/25px 'Graphik-Regular'; 
       padding-bottom:10px;
 }
.card_text h2{
       font:20px/22px 'Graphik-Medium';
 }
.card_text a.hidn{
       position:absolute; 
       bottom:15%; 
       font:14px/22px 'Graphik-Medium'; 
       color:#fff; 
       display:none;
 }
.card_container:hover .card_text .pre_state{
       top:0; 
       background-color:rgba(51,154,205,0.7); 
       transition:all .5s ease-out, all 0.5s ease-in; 
       transform:none;
}
.card_container:hover .card_text a.hidn{
      display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card_container">
  <div class="card_text">
    <div class="pre_state">
      <h5>20 Oktober 2018</h5>
    <h2>Vestibulum facilisis, tortor atrutrum cursus.</h2>
      <a href="#" class="hidn">Read more &gt; </a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like `calc` is only partially supported in IE 9 - https://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @Mohammad that didn't solved my problem

Comment: IE 9 doesn't support `transition` as you can see in https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: I don't know what version of IE its Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: First you said *I'm currently using IE 9*

Comment: Sorry my bad I don't know much about version numbers can you suggest an answer for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you clearly stated that sliding animation not working in IE its just because IE just don't support/partially support the `calc()` propoerty

BTW.. Why are you giving `top:calc(100% - 30%);` you can directly mention it as `top:70%;`

Try this

```css
.card_container{ 
        position:relative; 
        width:280px; 
        margin:auto; 
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
        height:450px; overflow:hidden;
      }
.card_text{
       position:absolute; 
       color:#fff; 
       height:100%; 
       width:100%; 
       top:0; 
       left:0;
     }
.card_text .pre_state {
       position:absolute; 
       /*top:calc(100% - 30%); */
       top: 70%;
       width:100%; 
       padding:30px 15px 25px; 
       height:100%; 
       transform:translate(0%, -30px);
}
.card_text h5{
       font:14px/25px 'Graphik-Regular'; 
       padding-bottom:10px;
 }
.card_text h2{
       font:20px/22px 'Graphik-Medium';
 }
.card_text a.hidn{
       position:absolute; 
       bottom:15%; 
       font:14px/22px 'Graphik-Medium'; 
       color:#fff; 
       display:none;
 }
.card_container:hover .card_text .pre_state{
       top:0; 
       background-color:rgba(51,154,205,0.7); 
       transition:all .5s ease-out, all 0.5s ease-in; 
       transform:none;
}
.card_container:hover .card_text a.hidn{
      display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card_container">
  <div class="card_text">
    <div class="pre_state">
      <h5>20 Oktober 2018</h5>
    <h2>Vestibulum facilisis, tortor atrutrum cursus.</h2>
      <a href="#" class="hidn">Read more &gt; </a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

> References:
>   https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/calc-not-always-working-in-ie/
>
> Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Thank you I was scratching head to fix this sliding problem also thanks for the references